# Can't connect JBPM service to Postgress service, both are using the same container

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, jbpm, icmp

I am using this docker - compose.yml.

```
    
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.3-alpine
    volumes:
    - C:\Postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: jbpm      
      POSTGRES_USER: jbpm
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: jbpm
    ports:
    - 5432:5432
    
  jbpm:
    image: quay.io/kiegroup/jbpm-server-full
    environment:
      JBPM_DB_DRIVER: postgres
      JBPM_DB_HOST: postgres
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    - 8001:8081
    depends_on:
    - postgres
```

But i keep receiving the message error:

```
| 23:15:58,475 INFO  [io.jaegertracing.internal.reporters.RemoteReporter] (jaeger.RemoteReporter-QueueProcessor) FlushCommand is working again!
jbpm_1      | 23:16:07,477 WARN  [io.jaegertracing.internal.reporters.RemoteReporter] (jaeger.RemoteReporter-QueueProcessor) FlushCommand execution failed! Repeated errors of this command will not be logged.: io.jaegertracing.internal.exceptions.SenderException: Failed to flush spans.
jbpm_1      |   at io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.thrift.internal.senders.ThriftSender.flush(ThriftSender.java:115)
jbpm_1      |   at io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.internal.reporters.RemoteReporter$FlushCommand.execute(RemoteReporter.java:160)
jbpm_1      |   at io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.internal.reporters.RemoteReporter$QueueProcessor.run(RemoteReporter.java:182)
jbpm_1      |   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
jbpm_1      | Caused by: io.jaegertracing.internal.exceptions.SenderException: Could not send 1 spans
jbpm_1      |   at io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.thrift.internal.senders.UdpSender.send(UdpSender.java:85)
jbpm_1      |   at io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.thrift.internal.senders.ThriftSender.flush(ThriftSender.java:113)
jbpm_1      |   ... 3 more
jbpm_1      | Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Cannot flush closed transport
jbpm_1      |   at io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.thrift.internal.reporters.protocols.ThriftUdpTransport.flush(ThriftUdpTransport.java:148)
jbpm_1      |   at org.apache.thrift@0.13.0//org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:73)
jbpm_1      |   at org.apache.thrift@0.13.0//org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBaseOneway(TServiceClient.java:66)
jbpm_1      |   at io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.agent.thrift.Agent$Client.send_emitBatch(Agent.java:70)
jbpm_1      |   at io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.agent.thrift.Agent$Client.emitBatch(Agent.java:63)
jbpm_1      |   at io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.thrift.internal.senders.UdpSender.send(UdpSender.java:83)
jbpm_1      |   ... 4 more
jbpm_1      | Caused by: java.net.PortUnreachableException: ICMP Port Unreachable
jbpm_1      |   at java.base/java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
jbpm_1      |   at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:695)
jbpm_1      |   at io.jaegertracing.jaeger@1.5.0//io.jaegertracing.thrift.internal.reporters.protocols.ThriftUdpTransport.flush(ThriftUdpTransport.java:146)
jbpm_1      |   ... 9 more
jbpm_1      |
jbpm_1      | 23:16:08,477 IN
```

The documentation can be found in https://www.jbpm.org/learn/gettingStartedUsingDocker.html. And some examples in https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/business-central/tree/main/docker-compose-examples.

Can you help me? I have been trying several suggestions but none works.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use it in standalone.xml, You can disable this by remove :

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:microprofile-opentracing-smallrye:3.0" default-tracer="jaeger">
<jaeger-tracer name="jaeger">
    <sampler-configuration sampler-type="const" sampler-param="1.0"/>
</jaeger-tracer>
```